# Configuring log4j file in Spring Boot using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I use a `JSON` file for `log4j` configuration in a `Spring Boot` project. I excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` and added `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` in the `pom` file.
If I place the `log4j2` file on `classpath`, I see logs are written to files properly, as designed. However, when I set `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` on start up, the log files are created but are empty and all the logs are written to the console. To test if the file is read, in debug I see that the `JSON` file is found and read. Also, when I set a fake location, the app does not start at all and instead throws a `file not found` exception. It shows that the configuration file is found, I believe.

`log4j` version is `2.7`.
`Spring boot` version is `1.5.10`.

Comment: try with `-Dlogging.config=<full-path-to>log4j2.json`

Comment: note that `logging.config` is the spring-boot property for the location of the configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the Appender added in the log4j configuration. The default would be ConsoleAppender. Can you please try adding RollingFileAppender

Also you may have to create the log directory which should be the immediate parent of the desired log file.

Comment: Thanks Sandip. I have 2 ref in root one for console and file, I also have a logger  for a specific logging class. As I said when config file is found on classpath root it creates all log directories, files and logs as expected and properly